# How to declare a new activity in Android manifest?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-manifest

I've followed the Android docs in adding a new activity to the manifest, but when I try to navigate to the class using a button click event I get a null pointer exception.

I gather from this that the class isn't being recognized as being present. To debug this I substituted the class name for `.SearchTree` and it navigated succesfully.

Can anyone see where I've made a mistake in the manifest?

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name=".SearchResult">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchTree"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

    </application>
```

This is the error in full detail below:

`E/AndroidRuntime(3508): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ie.gmit.computing/ie.gmit.computing.SearchResult}: java.lang.NullPointerException`
`

Comment: can you post a code from SearchResult activity? It could be a issue in its onCreate() method

Comment: "I gather from this that the class isn't being recognized as being present" -- no, it does not. Please post the entire stack trace, plus the relevant code that is triggering this exception.

Comment: For the names try something like : com.example.package.MainActivity

Comment: are you sure that the class SearchResult expanded the Activity?

Comment: @CommonsWare is right, I believe you would be experiencing a `ClassNotFoundException` if that were the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the `null pointer exception` turned out to be because I left out the below line of code from the onCreate();

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_result);`